# DLW-1 and DLW-2 flags

Tags: flag

What are the various flags in DLW-1 and DLW-2 microprocessors?
I have read about sign flag, overflow flag and zero flag but im not sure
Also it will be really helpful if you know a source from where i can read more about these two microprocessors

Comment: What microprocessors? Link to datasheet in your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the DLW-1 and DLW-2 are mythical microcprocessors used in a book on computer architecture by Jon Stokes (http://www.inside-the-machine.com/).  These processors only exist in Jon Stoke's mind - you'll have to read his book to find out more about those flags (but the function of those flags shoul be obvious from their names.)